# How do I use a static function in blade.php tempate in laravel 4?

Tags: methods, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have a class public static method that grabs some database information and returns a integer. In a controller i can call that method just fine. How do i call that static method in a blade template?

For example:

```
@foreach ($tasks as $task)
  {{Task::percentComplete($task->id)}}%<br />
@endforeach
```

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could either

A- Make it a Facade : http://laravel.com/docs/facades

B- Move it into a helper/library : https://stackoverflow.com/a/13481218/2446119

I personally think that helpers and libraries are much easier and quicker to code, but facades are cleaner.

Comment: Here is another good resource:http://jasonlewis.me/article/laravel-4-develop-packages-using-the-workbench

Answer (score 0):

One hackish way to do it is just embedding PHP in your blade template, at least in Laravel 4.0; I migrated an old project, poorly written, to laravel. Being so overwhelmed by the number of issues I ran into and time constraints I did not have time to look for a better way to do it. I did a bunch of html forms totaling about 30k lines of code.

```
<?php
 $haystack=Session::get('orderInfo.form.conditions',array());
?>
```

Then you can access your data normally:

```
{{in_array('Special Assignments',$haystack)?'checked="checked"':''}}
```

That's what worked for me.

> NOTE: Just adding my 2 cents for the sake of documentation. There are
>   better and cleaner ways to do it, as stated by the accepted answer.